# migration sharepoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, content-database, migration

I try to migrate site collection from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. But I can't see my site in the new URL, I have a default SharePoint site.

```
PS C:\Users\svc-bpm-sysadmin> Test-SPSite -Identity http://dv55udb01/
Test-SPSite : SPSiteHealthChecker: The element 'Rule' cannot contain child
element 'RegexExclusionFilters' because the parent element's content model is
empty.
 SPSite="http://dv55udb01"
 ruleId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 repair=False
 CompatibilityLevel=15
 registrationFolderPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web
Server Extensions\15\CONFIG\SiteHealthCheck"
 registrationFileName="sitehealthofficeserverrules.xml"
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-SPSite -Identity http://dv55udb01/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletTestSite:
   SPCmdletTestSite) [Test-SPSite], SPSiteHealthCheckerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletTestSite
```

I am have same error when I try to `Repair-SPSite`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you migrated the site?

Comment: hello,
1- create a new web application and new site collection in the new server
2- export the features (Add-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution )
3- backup restore the wss_content database
4- Test-SPContentDatabase  and Mount-SPContentDatabase

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the right cmdlet for migrating the Site collection .

The First step would be to take a backup of your existing site collection using the PowerShell below-

```
Backup-SPSite https://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

This will create a .bak file which is a backup of you site collection. Copy this file to a directory in the server where your SharePoint 2013 farm is present.

Now use the Power shell below to restore the .bak file to a new content database.

```
Restore-SPSite https://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

The only thing is that yoou must have a new content database created at the SP 2013 farm where you will restore the .bak file .

Simple !!

Comment: Hello,
im not in the same server 
the 2013 server is a new server

Comment: `code`
PS C:\Users\svc-bpm-sysadmin> Move-SPSite http://alcorg2-dev.finance.*.fr/ -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content_new_80
Move-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:
http://alcorg2-dev.finance.francetelecom.fr/.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-SPSite http://alcorg2-dev.finance.*.fr/ -Destination ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:
   SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite
`code`

Comment: Got it . Let me edit and change the answer .

Comment: I hope you got what to do . Run the first powershell in the SP2010 environment . You will get a .bak file which is the backup of your site . Now create a content database (new and blank) in your SP2013 environment . Copy the .bak to the SP2013 server . Run the second powershell that picks up the .bak obtained earlier and restores it to the newly created content database. This way your site collection gets migrated. Let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: thanks for your comment 

i have this error in restore:
Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite http://dv55udb01/ -Path \\DVEDVK87.rouen.*...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
   SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
   ite

Comment: Ah !! Got your issue . See now this error is because your SP2010 and SP2013 environments are not at the same CU level . If you check your ULS logs you will find one line like this "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Schema version of backup 15.0.4617.1000 does not match current schema version "Version here" at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)" .As I said in my answer your 2010 and 2013 environments must be in same patch level or migration via any way will not suceed .

Comment: Check if CU for both environments are same using the steps below - On the Central Administration opening page under “System Settings”, select “Manage servers in this farm”. 3. At the top of this page, you will see the Database configuration version number. This is the build number of your SharePoint Cumulative Update or Patch Level.

Comment: ok i try to see the cu level issu

Comment: Let me know if the CU levels are different

Comment: in the 2010 server i have 14.0.6029.1000
in the 2013 server i have 15.0.4569.1000
haw i can upgrade or downgrade this version

Comment: Upgrade-SPContentDatabase "Name of Content Database" -NoB2BSiteUpgrade  . Use this powershell in SP 2010 and once this suceeds try restore .

Comment: Upgrade-SPContentDatabase "WSS_Content" -NoB2BSiteUpgrade in the source server (2010) ? aftre i try to backup/restore ?

Comment: Yes correct. Try the Upgrade powershell in 2010 first . Then backup powershell and then restore. Make sure the to enter the correct name of database in the Upgrade cmdlet

Comment: PS C:\Users\adm-55u> Upgrade-SPContentDatabase "WSS_Content" -NoB2BSiteUpgrade
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
name 'NoB2BSiteUpgrade'.
At line:1 char:58
+ Upgrade-SPContentDatabase "WSS_Content" -NoB2BSiteUpgrade <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase]
   , ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.Powe
   rShell.SPCmdletUpgradeContentDatabase

Comment: You may have to upgrade the SP2010 environment which is the last resort . Let me point you to a link .  https://kamdaryash.wordpress.com/2019/06/08/psconfig-terminates-giving-error-as-command-is-incorrect-microsoft-sharepoint-postsetupconfigurationtaskexception-thrown/ .  There is a link in my blog for patching . You will have to follow it

Comment: Hello 
does this migration not impact our existing environment ?

Comment: No the migration won't impact your existing environment because you are only taking a backup of existing site collection and restoring it to another environment . Were you able to perform the patching successfully  ?Patching your environment is very important since it keeps your environment updated with all hotfixes from microsoft and solves vulnerabilities identified by MS